# Penny round up in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Pennie round up work like this

For amount like 10.31 or 10.32 it becomes 10.30
For amount 10.33 and 10.34 it becomes 10.35
For amount 10.36 and 10.37 it becomes 10.35
For amount 10.38 and 10.39 it becomes 10.40

Please help me to achieve like this, I tried everything but no success, I will always thankful...

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Times it by 20, round it, divide it by 20. Please take the site tour

Comment: I have a rule, if it is money use Decimal data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a function that demonstrates how you can use the [Mod operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/mod-operator) to get a remainder from a number and choose what to do with it:

```
Public Function RoundPenny(amount As Single) As Single

    Dim integerAmount As Integer = amount * 100
    Dim remainder As Integer = integerAmount Mod 5

    Select Case remainder
        Case 0, 1, 2
            integerAmount -= remainder
        Case 3, 4
            integerAmount += (5 - remainder)
    End Select

    Return integerAmount / 100

End Function
```